# Migrate BizTalk Server from local server to remote server

Tags: biztalk, biztalk-2016

I have BizTalk 2016 server running on my local machine and want to migrate all the settings and applications to remote server. I am trying to implement using BizTalk migration tool provided by Microsoft [Announcing: BizTalk Server Migration tool](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/biztalk_server_team_blog/2017/06/28/announcing-biztalk-server-migration-tool/)

Would appreciate if provided a sample demo on this application/tool or any other implementation available to migrate.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow.  Please read the Help Center, especially  what is on-topic.  "Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it."   So have you tried to tool, and are you having any specific issues?

Comment: Did you see the link to the User Guide at the bottom of the BizTalk Server Migration tool announcement?  For a small guide take a look here https://1drv.ms/w/s!ArAuxhUkaVzpbfAivQfWRaeRun4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My advice, don't bother with this tool.  I've never even heard of it so...no one is actually using it.... ;)

Anyway, the correct procedure is very simple...

1. Build new BizTalk Server environment
2. Deploy your apps

   - Export .msi and bindings
   - OR -
   - Build the apps with BizTalk Deployment Framework